# Difference between jitter buffer and playout buffer in WebRTC

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, chromium

What is the difference between 'jitter buffer' and 'playout buffer' in WebRTC? Do they refer to the same buffer or are they different?

Answer (score 1):

I think they refer to same buffer. 
Check out this paper https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/41611.pdf which described the architecture
[image]

After the JB, the image is sent to decoder. It seems like Playout buffer is same as JB.